# Finder "Arrange by kind" on Sierra shows only Folders & "Other"

Tags: macos, mac, finder

Strangely, when using 'Arrange By -> Kind' in MacOS Sierra, Finder only distinguishes between Folders and 'other'.

[image: Example of Finder window with Arrange By Kind]

I have rebuilt the LaunchServices database, deleted my Finder PList, edited and removed the CoreTypes bundle strings (`/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`) all to no avail.

My colleagues, who run the exact same version of Sierra on the same Macbook builds, don't have this problem and see their files arranged neatly as 'Images', 'Documents', etcetera.

Apart from ‘reinstall Sierra from scratch’, any ideas?

Comment: Might be related to what you have set as available categories in System Prefs > Spotlight

Comment: @Tetsujin that's it!! Last thing I would've thought of. Thanks a bunch. If you want, make this an answer and i'll check it as answered

Comment: Sure thing - was a just a guess, but seemed a fair possibility :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear to be related to the Categories you have set in System Prefs > Spotlight > Search Results...

[image]

<sup>Pic from El Cap, but I doubt it has changed much</sup>